# Reduce indentation of treeview nodes in Outline View in Eclipse Juno SR1

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

In the Eclipse (Juno SR1 Build id: 20120920-0800) Outline View pane, it lists my Account class in a treeview control. The node expands out, and then it shows members of the class including constants, methods, etc.

The indentation from one level to the next in this treeview is extremely wasteful in regards to screen space.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to reduce this indentation, so that the level of nodes below the class node are not so far indented. Is there a setting in Preferences for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has no control over this. The outline is a standard tree control whose appearance is controlled by your OS.

Comment: Clearly, not all of Eclipse's interface is controlled by the OS. It may be so that by default, it uses the OS's standard style, but just as many programs override this style, I would expect Eclipse to offer similar functionality. It is written in Java after all, which I suspect simply encapsulates some cross-platform specifics on how to style each OS's tree view control - something similar to the way Qt handles cross platform treeview controls.

Comment: What you are wishing for does not exist. Basic OS controls have certain level of flexibility and that's accessible to Eclipse. Indentation of items in a tree is not something that you control. This may be possible in some advanced custom-rendered toolkits like Qt, but Eclipse isn't built on Qt.